# Stuck running a SMOTE implementation on PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

So, for personal project I tried using this [PySpark SMOTE Implementation](https://gist.github.com/inguelberth/547db5aef8fb82527c79b1d6e2fc368c) to handle an imbalanced flight data that looks like this:

| CRS_DEP_TIME | DEP_TIME | CRS_ARR_TIME | DISTANCE | YEAR_IDX | DAY_OF_WEEK_IDX | DEST_IDX | ORIGIN_IDX | MONTH_OF_YEAR_IDX | OP_CARRIER_IDX | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 715 | 709 | 1014 | 630 | 2 | 1 | 15 | 30 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2141 | 2153 | 2234 | 630 | 2 | 1 | 30 | 15 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

I got the data from [this Kaggle dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/yuanyuwendymu/airline-delay-and-cancellation-data-2009-2018) and after split, the training data contains around 2.1GB, 34M rows, with probably around 1:7 imbalance. I know it is not that big of an imbalance but I just wanna try the implementation.

The main goal is to make a classification model that can predict whether a flight will arrive late or not, with 1 as late and 0 as not in the label column y.

I've tried running this on Google Colab. Note that both the `smote` and `pre_smote_df_process` function is the one from the PySpark SMOTE Implementation.

```
class SmoteConfig:
  def __init__(self, seed, bucketLength, k, multiplier):
    self.seed = seed
    self.bucketLength = bucketLength
    self.k = k
    self.multiplier = multiplier

config = SmoteConfig(76, 200, 3, 2)

train_smoted = smote(pre_smote_df_process(train,['CRS_DEP_TIME','DEP_TIME','CRS_ARR_TIME','DISTANCE'],['YEAR_IDX','DAY_OF_WEEK_IDX','DEST_IDX','ORIGIN_IDX','MONTH_OF_YEAR_IDX','OP_CARRIER_IDX'],'y',index_suffix="_index"), config)
    train_smoted.show()
```

When I tried using a fraction of the data (up to 1%) it works witin reasonable time. However, when I ran it on 10% data it took me more than 14 hours to show the result, and using 100% data this following error came up.

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-6919ba1953f2> in <module>()
----> 1 disassembled.coalesce(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save("/content/drive/MyDrive/Tugas/Tugas Akhir/Eksperimen/lsh_smoted_18_05_21.csv",header = 'true')

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o12989.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:231)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:188)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:131)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:132)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:131)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:772)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:438)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:293)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
 at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
 at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
 at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
 at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
 at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
 at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 28 in stage 745.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 28.0 in stage 745.0 (TID 34904) (55fc2b589d8c executor driver): java.io.IOException: No space left on device
 at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:354)
 at org.apache.spark.storage.TimeTrackingOutputStream.write(TimeTrackingOutputStream.java:59)
 at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
 at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
 at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.finish(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:263)
 at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.close(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:193)
 at java.base/java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:188)
 at java.base/java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:188)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeRowSerializerInstance$$anon$1.close(UnsafeRowSerializer.scala:96)
 at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.commitAndGet(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:175)
 at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:163)
 at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
 at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
 at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
 at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
 Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
  at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
  at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:354)
  at org.apache.spark.storage.TimeTrackingOutputStream.write(TimeTrackingOutputStream.java:59)
  at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
  at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
  at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.flush(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:243)
  at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:143)
  at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeRowSerializerInstance$$anon$1.flush(UnsafeRowSerializer.scala:91)
  at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.commitAndGet(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:173)
  at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.$anonfun$close$1(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:156)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
  at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.close(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:158)
  at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:164)
  ... 10 more
  Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
   at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
   at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:354)
   at org.apache.spark.storage.TimeTrackingOutputStream.write(TimeTrackingOutputStream.java:59)
   at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
   at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
   at java.base/java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:182)
   at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter$ManualCloseBufferedOutputStream$1.org$apache$spark$storage$DiskBlockObjectWriter$ManualCloseOutputStream$$super$close(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:108)
   at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter$ManualCloseOutputStream.manualClose(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:65)
   at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter$ManualCloseOutputStream.manualClose$(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:64)
   at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter$ManualCloseBufferedOutputStream$1.manualClose(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:108)
   at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.$anonfun$closeResources$1(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:135)
   at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
   at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.closeResources(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:136)
   at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.$anonfun$close$2(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:158)
   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1448)
   ... 12 more

Driver stacktrace:
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2253)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2202)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2201)
 at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
 at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
 at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2201)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1078)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1078)
 at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1078)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2440)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2382)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2371)
 at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:868)
 at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContex
```

On the resource monitor, the disk constantly creeps up until full, before the error mentioned occurs.

Running it on local also shows the same error. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Is the code unoptimized? Or there might possibly be something wrong with the data? Any insight will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

since you say it works fine when you use fraction of data, and considering the error that i see here, it seems like memory problem. I didn't use this code. i used SMOTE() in imblearn library and that works fine with my PySpark project(maybe consider using that too). but for this kind of error, increasing memory worked for me.

you can increase memory in this way:
I used Google Colab like you and when i wanted to create a SparkSession instance i changed it to :

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local")\
                        .appName("your_project_Name")\
                        .config("spark.ui.port",'4050')\
                        .config("spark.driver.memory","32G")\
                        .config("spark.executer.memory","32G")\
                        .getOrCreate()
```

it worked for me. hope it helps you and others too.
but generally,if data is still so big and even if you don't want to just use Undersampling, you can use combination of Undersampling with other methods(basic Oversampling or others). in this way you can reduce some memory problems.